# Updating by multiple checkboxes on Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I have a Patient model that has `knowndiseases` column. It stores an array of strings of particular diseases such as DM, HT etc. I want my patient to be able to update his/her knowndiseases column by checking these checkboxes and posting the form.

Once I send the form, I can see the values of selected checkboxes as an array, at `params[:knowndiseases]`. However, when I pas these values with a user_params method, the patient record at the database does not get updated.

I tried again this with removing the `:multiple => true` option at my checkboxes, and this time my patient got updated by only the last value that is checked, not with others.

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @patient, url: update_profile_part2_path(@patient), :method => 'patch', :html => {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'DM', nil%> DM 

<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'HT', nil%> HT 

<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'KAH', nil %> KAH 

<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'Astım', nil %> Astım 

<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'Malignite', nil %> Malignite 

<%= f.check_box :knowndiseases, { :multiple => true}, 'Guatr', nil %> Guatr 
<% end %>
```

and the migration I've used for creating the knowndiseases column:

```
add_column :users, :knowndiseases, :string, array: true
```

Shortly, what can I do to update `knowndiseases` attribute with the array that is passed by `params[:knowndiseases]`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to possibly create a HABTM relationship between patient and known diseases that way @patient.knowndiseases would hold that information you are passing in via the form. If you decide to go that way the check_box_tag would be extremely useful because it lets Rails do its backend magic. Separating known diseases into it's own model allows for more control in the future if another known diseases needs to be added to the database. It also makes it more portable

For example, with a HABTM relationship between the two on the simple form you could have

```
<%for known in Knowndiseases.all %>
<%= check_box_tag "patient[knowndiseases_ids][]", known.id, @patient.knowndiseases.include?(known)%>
<% known.name %>
<%end%>
```

In your controller you will still pass in a params for a :knowndieases [] and in the update method be sure to put the following to account for an empty array.

```
def update
params[:patient][:knowndieases_ids] ||= []
end
```